# Replacing Svg text with plain text in firefox

Tags: firefox, text, svg, shapes

I've made a shape with a text inside and save it as svg (in ilustrator). The font I've chosen (AndaleMono) is working properly on Chrome, Safari and Opera, but Firefox is rendering another default font.
I would like to display the text in the shape in the browsers that can display the 'custom' font and display in Firefox a 'paragraph' tag with the text font taken from a @font-face rule.
The html tree looks something like this:

```
<svg class="text-shape">
<polygon points="-13.878,39.319 47.762,-3.634 389.206,108.691 323.906,147.925 "/>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 25.9165 19.0337)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'AndaleMono'" font-size="12">O es una </tspan><tspan x="-20.665" y="14.4" font-family="'AndaleMono'" font-size="12">mesa de centro </tspan><tspan x="-13.328" y="28.8" font-family="'AndaleMono'" font-size="12">cortada a laser</tspan></text>
</svg>
<p>O es una mesa de centro cortada a laser</p>
```

The svg element should be only displayed in the proper browser (and not displaying the paragraph tag) and viceversa.
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the font name shouldn't have a space in it (i.e., `'Andale Mono'` instead of `'AndaleMono'`)? Also, why aren't you specifying a default font family (i.e., `font-family="'AndaleMono',monospace"`)

Comment: @squeamishossifrage the `'AndaleMono'` name is generated by ilustrator (I asume is the proper way). Adding a fallback font family should be done in all the `tspan` elements (I think) and have a lot of pieces of text like the one above, so don't think is a good solution. I just want to display the text without shape in firefox.

Comment: When working with SVGs, never assume Illustrator is doing things correctly. You can use a CSS rule to apply the same font style to all your SVG text elements (e.g., `svg text { font-family:AndaleMono,'Andale Mono',monospace; }`

Comment: Thank you so much @squeamishossifrage. It worked fine. Finally the font name `'Andale Mono'` should have a space between the words for Firefox to understand it. :-)